# Rails DELETE call won't work even though UJS is loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Totally exhausted all my brain power on this one. I'm using devise to manage users in a rails 4 application. I have two parts of the app. The admin side and the user side.

Destroying sessions on the Admin side works fine but the user side is calling a GET rather than DELETE.

Here's some code:

layouts/discover.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "user/discover_application", media: "all"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'user/discover_application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

layouts/discover/_modal.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
   <li><%= link_to(raw('<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout'), destroy_user_session_path, :method => "delete")%></li>
 <% else %>
    <li><%= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login'), new_user_session_path%></li>
 <% end %>
```

assets/javascripts/user/discover_application.js

```
//= require user/modernizr
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions"}
 resources :users
 root :to => "discover#index"
```

I have pretty much the exact same thing on the admin side and it's working properly so I'm completely lost. There are no javascript errors and the markup that rails renders shows the data-method as delete. Any help is most appreciated.

UPDATED

Actual Link Generated by Rails

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
```

Logs:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-22 22:22:16 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"sign_out"}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "sign_out"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 52ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User with id=sign_out:
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:198:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:284:in `find_one'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:268:in `find_with_ids'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:35:in `find'
  activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:122:in `find'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `show'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run__1114563881307914935__process_action__callbacks'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1405362911685491265__call__callbacks'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
   () Users/niknjegovan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `require'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post your logs? The potential issues I can see are either that Devise is being overridden / confused with the multiple types of record (`user` & `admin`), or your link is not being shown properly. Logs will help tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

Is there some js that intercepts the natural link_to (`<a>`) behavior? Because if not `<a href>` is always a GET request.

Comment: My expectation is that UJS will take care of the call as it does on the admin side, though your comment makes me wonder if there's possibly some JS in this codebase that might be overriding UJS. I'll explore that a bit.